# Удалил таблицу из базы данных вручную и теперь не понимаю, как ее восстановить с помощью миграций в Django

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, миграция

В проекте в бд создал таблицу с помощью миграций, после этого удалил ее вручную с помощью интерфейса PgAdmins, теперь хочу восстановить эту таблицу, но когда пишу python3 manage.py migrate пишет No migrations to apply.
Пытался откатить миграции с помощью python manage.py migrate AppName zero, но эффект такой же.
Как мне восстановить эту таблицу с помощью миграций?

Comment: Удалили вручную — значит и восстанавливайте вручную, миграции тут уже ни при чём

Answer (score 0):

Была такая же проблема. На самом деле, если у тебя не хранится ничего важного в ней. То просто удали её полностью и создай новую. Данные в любом случае можно заполнить вручную через сам PGAdmin.